# Test Explorer in VS Shell Isolated to use existing features

Tags: c#, test-explorer, visual-studio-shell

I'd like to program my own little software using the VS Isolated Shell 2015.

My question is, is it possible to add e.g. existing packages/features such as Test Explorer to the isolated shell?

I figured out, that i would need to add the GUID and packages folder, but could not find any reference such as commands to add it to the main menu bar such as `Test Explorer Context Menu`.

What is missing?

I just need to know if it possible -> otherwise I would need to develop the Test Explorer as an extension.